# How to backup running keycloak instance?

Tags: keycloak

iam following the keycloak.org doc to backup my keycloak Data:

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#_export_import

> bin/standalone.sh -Dkeycloak.migration.action=export Dkeycloak.migration.provider=dir -Dkeycloak.migration.dir=/opt/keycloak/backup

My problem is, that this works only when the keycloak service is stopped. How can i export this data while my keycloak is running? On Production i cant stop my server.

Any ideas?

I found not really helpful information about this ...

Comment: https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2018-February/013012.html

Comment: Thanks, yes i found this alredy. But if i start a second instance of keycloak to backup this way, how can i stop the second instance after backup? is killing by pid really the right way and best practice?

Comment: Yes, killing by pid is the right way.

Comment: Thank your for your fast help!